# How to return more than one value in a Thrift service method?

Tags: c++, thrift

I have a thrift service method `ImportantData GetImportantData()` defined in the IDL. I would like to return a Status code for this method. I would like to be doing some thing like `Status GetImportantData(ImportantData&)` Is there a way to do that?

I have gone through multiple thrift tutorials like
Thrift By Example

- [Thrift By Example](http://thrift-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage-example.html)
- [Apache Thrift Documentation](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/idl)
- [Thrift the missing guide](http://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way - include `Status` inside `ImportantData`.

Thrift has to be portable - not every language supports output parameters (references etc.) so Thrift can't support it neither. So there can be only one returned object.

Usually best solution, providing nice future compatibility etc. is to create `FunctionReturn` struct (in your example containing `ImportantData` and `Status`). This way some more return values can be added if needed.

BTW: if `Status` is there to indicate possible errors and it will be `StatusOk` most of the time, think about returning `ImportantData` and throwing exceptions (which are supported by Thrift) if error occurred. Such solution would look much nicer in C++ (as always - exceptional situations - errors - should be covered by exceptions).

Comment: I've a different opionion regarding `out/ref/var` parameters but that's a whole other story. I just don't find the JIRA ticket where I outlined the general idea quite detailed. The key is, that call args and retvals (including exceptions) are wrapped into a structure anyway on the wire. So there is no real technical reason why we can't have multiple retvals, which in essence are only syntactic sugar for `out`. As long as the language supports any kind of structured data, it is feasible.

Comment: @JensG I agree with you. But for now, since thrift does not support out param, I have already used Status inside ImportantData.